# Replacing text of one tag with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu here:

```
<header></header>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Something</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Something1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Something2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#">Something3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on a link within the menu, how do I get whatever link they clicked to show up within the header tag? So if a user picks the second link, Something2, I want whatever the text is between the a tag, in this case Something2, to show up between the header tag.

Comment: i've tried using FieldRenderer, but that only displays whatever page I'm on and not the link itself. Tried hardcoding it but the levels get too deep to do that, so I'm trying the Javascript route but not sure of what to try, thats why I'm asking

Comment: you're basically saying you want one link's text to change to another link's text, well you should probably look into ID's and selectors using jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of working examples for your context in SO. Its very simple in jquery and you asking very hard. Please look through [API Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/)

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('header').text($(this).text());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0xrxeufh/)

**for your second question** "I have a back button, how do I revert the previous link back to what it was? "

```
var temp = '';

$("ul li a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     temp = $('header').text();
     $('header').data('value', temp);
     $('header').text($(this).text());
    });

$(".back").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $('header').data('value');
    $('header').text(val);
});
```

[**Fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/0xrxeufh/1/)

Comment: Ok this works, but I have a back button, how do I revert the previous link back to what it was?

Comment: I didn't add it, it wasn't important when I first asked the question but its outside the ul tags

Comment: I see this works in your fiddle, but in mine when I click back, it replaces 'header' with the word back

Comment: No chance at all. I guess you first time directly click on back button or one time click the menu and click back button also header is empty

Comment: yeah initially the header tag is empty except for the very first time, the next headers are empty to be replaced with whatever is clicked

Comment: I'll try to figure it out I guess, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
    var element = document.getElementById("header");
    element.innerHTML = $(this).text();
});
```

You can try something like this to modify the header text whenever a link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
  $('header').html($(this).text());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tm6SH/59/)

Comment: This works as well, but not sure if there is a way to revert to the previous li tag when clicking back

Comment: you mean browser's back button?

Comment: no I added the code up top, I have an a href tag outside the ul tags to click back to the previous menu

Answer (score 1):

I have set up a fiddle with the following (also takes care of the back button): https://jsfiddle.net/0dLy3xwq/2/

HTML:

```
<header id="linkLabel"></header>
<a href="#" id="backButton">Back</a>
<ul id="navigationList">
    <li>
       <a href="#">Something</a>
    </li>
   <li>
       <a href="#">Something1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="#">Something2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="#">Something3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
    var navStack = [];

    $('#navigationList a').click(function (event) {
        var el = $(event.target),
            label = el.text();

        if (navStack[navStack.length - 1] !== label) {
            navStack.push(label);
            updateView();
        }
    });

    $('#backButton').click(function () {
        navStack.pop();
        updateView();
    });

    function updateView() {
        $('#linkLabel').text(navStack[navStack.length - 1] || '');   
    }
}(jQuery));
```

For the back button just use a simple stack to keep track of where the user has been. If you have a forward button then create another stack that pushes the popped label when back is clicked.