# Need a single text element not repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a problem from this question [Replacing text of one tag with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162128/replacing-text-of-one-tag-with-another) but basically this JavaScript function works, but when I click on the back button, instead of it producing a single text item, it repeats text 12 times and I can't figure out why.

```
<header></header>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
$(".back").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $('header').data('value');
  $('header').text(val);
});
```

So when I click the back button, instead of it returning "Topic 1", it returns in the header "Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1"

like this:

```
<header>Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1Topic 1</header>
<a class="back">Back</a>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Something3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: There is no data in header, why are you trying to get the value?

Comment: after this first click into the menu, the header will be filled with what the user clicked on, when you hit the back button it needs to go back to what was in the header originally

Comment: A jsfiddle reproducing the issue would be really helpful. Without any other information to go off of I would suspect that the class .back is being used someplace else(if not, why not make it an id to be more syntactically correct)?

Comment: There's no value in the header so how you return 12 "Topic 1" values is a miracle...unless you left out some code

Comment: This seems like something better resolved in the comments of the original question... if someone gave you an answer that is incorrect or isn't working, don't feel obliged to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is save the original value from the header and then replace the changed header value with the original when you click on the "back" button.
 Here is working code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        var original = $("header").text();

        $(".back").click(function (e) {            
            e.preventDefault();            
            $('header').text(original);
        });      
        
        $("li a").click(function (e) {            
            e.preventDefault();            
            $('header').text( $(this).text() );
        });  

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Original content</header>
<a class="back">Back</a>

<ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Something</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Something1</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Something2</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Something3</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```